# add asterix before and after value in cell.

Tags: vba, excel

I found this code online to help me print asterix before and after values in a column. 
The problem with this one is that it print 4 asterix if i have a selection of 4 rows in column a etc. I cant hardcode the range beacuse it differs from time to time. Sometimes i have 2 rows in column a with values and other times i have 5 or 7 and so on.

Do u have any tips for how i can solve this or any help? i cant figure out how to declare my ranges for example so it checks one cell at a time instead of a range of cells.

```
Sub Add_Asterisk()

Dim r As Range
 With Selection

    For Each r In Selection
        r.Value = "*" & r.Value & "*"
    Next
 End With


 End Sub
```

Thank u in advance
/D

Comment: can you show an example ? I tried your code in several scenarios, and it worked fine, adding a single `*` beofre and after my values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a variable to hold the last row with data in the desired column and then loop through all the cells in the set range.

```
Sub Add_Asterisk()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Rng As Range, Cell As Range

'Finding the last row with data in column A
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Setting the range in column A
Set Rng = Range("A2:A" & LastRow)

For Each Cell In Rng
    Cell.Value = "*" & Cell.Value & "*"
Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: THANK U! Sometimes i truly am an idiot! This goes down in my future vba toolbox!